# STM32F105RC not entering in DFU mode

Tags: usb, stm32, embedded

I am using STM32F105RC for a project. I am currently using ST-Link to program the MCU, but i plan to upload the program using DFU mode.

For this purpose i am trying make F105 enter into DFU mode with no success.

1. I have connected the PA9 to HIGH.
2. Connected USART1_RX (PA10) and CAN2_RX (PB5) pins to low as mentioned in AN2606.
3. They have also mentioned to connect USART2_RX (PD6) to low as well.

But Since i am using a 64 pins package PD6 does not exists instead PA3 pin has option of USART2_RX which is also connected to low.

But still i am not able to make MCU enter into DFU mode.

Getting DFU to work is very crucial for my project, please help me to get this working.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

P.S. In normal mode MCU's USB is set to work as VCP which is working fine. Hence the USB connection is working just as it should be.

Comment: Just to make sure: you did this following datasheet or random internet faq?

Comment: You left out tons of info. What state is  BOOT1 (PB2)? Do you have a crystal connected, and if yes, what frequency?

Comment: How should the DFU mode be activated (power cycle and pressing a button, software reset etc.)?

Comment: The way I read the documentation pins PA10, PB5 and PD6 are not relevant for DFU mode unless you have a date code below 937. If that was the case, it wouldn't work at all for 64 pin packages.

Comment: @llya, i did not found any relevant info about DFU wiring for the F105RC MCU but i followed the AN2606 pdf.

Comment: @Justme PB2 is not connected to anything (floating), yes have HSE at 8Mhz

Comment: @Codo The date code is 943/9 i checked that hence i am sure that DFU should work with this MCU. I am trying to enter DFU mode by setting the boot pin to HIGH and then powering the MCU. It does goes in the reset mode, cos the code stops working but when i connect to usb i get unrecognized device error.

Comment: PB2/BOOT1 must be low and BOOT0 must be high to enter bootloader after pulsing the reset pin or after powerup.

Comment: @Justme hmm i thought BOOT0 needs to be HIGH and boot1 is dont care. But let me try that tomorrow and will let you know how it went. So it needs to be LOW? floating or not connected wont work?

Comment: BOOT1 is not don't care, so leaving it floating or not connected will cause problems.

Comment: AN2606 states that the bootloader is activated by *pattern1* (ch 14.1, first sentence). *pattern1* is BOOT0 = 1 and BOOT1 = 0 (table 2, first row). The moment the bootloader starts, the USB cable must be connected. Otherwise it only checks USART and CAN (see figure 17).

Comment: @Codo i tried with BOOT0 = 1 and BOOT1 = 0 but still the same thing. Device Descriptor request failed.

Comment: Did you have the USB cable plugged in on powering the MCU up?

Comment: Yes thats how its powered.